# Почему в результат работы миксина добавляется лишний "px"?

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, scss

Написал такой миксин адаптивного свойства:

```
@import "./settings.scss";

@mixin adaptiveProperty($property, $startValue, $secondValue, $mode) {
    $addValue: $startValue-$secondValue;

    @if ($mode == 1) {
        @media (max-width: #{$maxWidthContainer+px}) {
            #{$property}: calc(
                #{$startValue+px}+$addValue * (100vw-#{$minWidth+px}) / (#{$maxWidthContainer+px}-#{$minWidth+px})
            );
        }
    } @else if ($mode == 2) {
        @media (min-width: #{$maxWidthContainer+px}) {
            #{$property}: calc(
                #{$startValue+px}+$addValue * (100vw-#{$minWidth+px}) / (#{$maxWidthContainer+px}-#{$minWidth+px})
            );
        }
    } @else {
        #{$property}: calc(#{$startValue+px}+(#{$addValue}* ((100vw-#{$minWidth+px}) / #{$maxWidth-$minWidth})));
    }
}
```

В файле `settings.scss` такие настройки:

```
$font-family: "Roboto";
$fontSize: 16;
$maxWidthContainer: 1000;
$maxWidth: 1920;
$minWidth: 320;
```

Теперь при вызове миксина таким образом:

```
.test_header{
    @include adaptiveProperty("font-size", 30, 16, 0) // Шрифт должен быть 30px на экране шириной 1920px и уменьшаться до 16px на 320px 
}
```

Но в скомпилированном css файле я получаю такое свойство:

```
.test_header {
  font-size: calc(
            30px+calc(30px-16px)px* (100vw-320px) / (1920px-320px)
        );
}
```

Там после скобки `calc(30px - 16 px)` лишние `px` и, кажется, лишний перевод строки. Думаю из-за этого мой миксин не работает. Как исправить формулу, чтобы убрать эти лишние `px` из готового результата?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня Ваш миксин заработал после того, как я поставил пробелы между всеми операторами. В частности, судя по css-файлу у Вас не считается переменная `$addValue`. Попробуйте заменить в миксине строку

`$addValue: $startValue-$secondValue;`

на

`$addValue: $startValue - $secondValue;`

Ну и дальше по коду отделите операторы пробелами от операндов.